# Error running call reference function

Tags: lua

I am having an error whilst trying to run a resource on a game server. I believe this line of code in the console is the issue;

```
Error running call reference function for resource es_extended: 
citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:351: server/main.lua:237: attempt to 
index a nil value (global 'Async')
```

I have been to line 351 to find this;

```
 error(err)
```

I then went to line 237 to find this;

```
    Async.parallel(tasks, function(results)
```

I cannot see for the life of me anything wrong with either lines of code. So any and all advice is greatly recieved.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS or HTML, so first - update tags, please.

Comment: This isn't C# either - according to the error it's Lua

Answer (score 1):

The global variable Async is a nil value. Hence indexing it like this:

```
Async.parallel
```

is not possible. Therefor Lua throws an error.

To fix it, find out why Async is nil and change that, or do not index it.